# what is "theme_setup" method for?

Tags: themes

I can always find some class contains `theme_setup` methods like below, but I never see this methods been called. I don't what's this method for.

```
<?php
  final class InfiniteScroll extends Package {

    protected static $single_instance = null;

    public static function theme_setup() {
        $is = self::get_instance();

        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array($is, 'infinite_scroll_js') );
    }

    /**
     * AJAX Function for infinite scroll
     */
    public function infinite_scroll() {
        ...some implement....
    }

    /**
     * Register js for Infinite Scroll
     */
    public function infinite_scroll_js() {
        ...some code here...
    }
}
```

Comment: theme initialisation, pretty sure it's called somewhere, you just have not found it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Methods in 3rd party plugin and theme classes can be called whatever the author wants them to be called. `theme_setup()` doesn't mean anything special, and doesn't even necessarily mean the same thing in different plugins.

And since it's not a special method to WordPress, they're never going to be called automatically by WordPress, so the plugin *would* be calling them somewhere, you just haven't found it. If I had to guess, `theme_setup()` is a logical name for a method that might be being hooked to `after_theme_setup`, but there's no guarantee.